# "Angular-Kendo UI" Is there a way to show a popup on node click on a kendo line chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I would need to understand how to show detailed data when clicking on the node.
The line chart has nodes/points and for each of these I have a detail/sub-object to show via a popup.

Can you tell me how I can implement something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the series click event. Modified one of kendo examples with  or you can view it https://angular-vktg91.stackblitz.io

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AxisLabelClickEvent, LegendItemClickEvent, LegendItemHoverEvent, PlotAreaClickEvent, PlotAreaHoverEvent, SeriesClickEvent, SeriesHoverEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-chart
            [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }"
            (render)="onRender()"
            (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)"
            >
            <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
            <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
            <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                    type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
        <event-log title="Event log" [events]="events"></event-log>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public events: string[] = [];
    public series = [{
            name: 'India',
            data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
        }, {
            name: 'Russian Federation',
            data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3]
        }, {
            name: 'Germany',
            data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995]
        }, {
            name: 'World',
            data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
        }];

    public categories: number[] = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];

    public onRender(): void {
        this.log('render', {});
    }

    public onSeriesClick(e: SeriesClickEvent): void {
        this.log('seriesClick', e);
    }

    private log(event: string, args: unknown): void {
        this.events.push(`${event}`);
        console.log(args);
    }
}
```

I took the code from this example on the different events available for Angular Chart and modified it a little bit https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/events/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34799797)

Comment: @Moken That's a very good point, I updated the answer to now include a modified code example from the linked pages in hope add clarity.